# Individual day data group into week and countif = A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, countif

I have a large excel spreadsheet which has a list of "items" in rows and a value per day in columns (which runs for over 500 columns) - for example refer to example:
***sample data***
[image]

What I need to do is count the number of "A" per week - refer to example:
[image]

I can manually get the calculation to work (as per the second image) however due the large amount of data I cant get it to automatically drag across.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to put extra line to your data table (for me under the line with dates), that will for each column tell you week1/week2/... 
The formula for this will be 
`="Week"&WEEKNUM(B2,1)`, where B2 = 1.1.2017
Than you can use Countifs formula.
The countifs formula will be:
 
`=COUNTIFS(4:4,"A",$3:$3,B$26)`
*There line B$26 is value "Week1" from your second chart, line $3:$3 is new line we created before and line 4:4 is line for item2 in first chart.*
Then just copy down and right and here you go. :-)

Comment: This is very close thank you very much.  I only have one final issue with the week function, I need it to count from week 1 past week 52, ie, week 53, week 54, etc

Comment: So, if I get it right, you do not care about end of year?

Comment: Correct, I just want the weeks to keep counting up.

Comment: So change weeknum(b2, 1) for roundup(counta($b$2:b$2)/7, 0). This should make it.